# Match snippets in an HTML document

Tags: search, nlp, fuzzy-search

Somebody has presented me with a very large list of copyedits to make to a long HTML document. The edits are in the format:

> "religious" should be "religions"
>   "their" should be "there"
>   "you must persistent" should be "you must be persistent"

The copyedits were typed by hand; in some cases, the "actual" value on the left is not an exact match for the content in the document. The order of edits is usually correct, but even that is not guaranteed.

It's a straightforward but very large task to apply these edits by hand to the document. I'd like to automate the process as much as possible, e.g. by automatically searching for the snippets.

In a long document like this, I can't just search for all instances of "their" and replace them with "there." Sometimes "their" was used correctly, just not in one particular instance.

In other words, I'm looking for a fuzzy text match, where the order of the edits influences the search.

What's a good approach to a problem like this? I'm hoping that there's some off-the-shelf open source project that can search for the snippets in a fuzzy order.

Comment: How much messed up the order can be?

Comment: @Jirka-x1 I don't know how to answer that question in a formal way. Let's assume that a given edit will be no more than a dozen places out of order. (I hope that's right.) So if "their"->"there" should be in position 20, it could be in position 10 or position 30 but not in position 1 or position 1000.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any tool. But I would use edit distance for both:

1. for non-exact string match: probably std. [Levenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) + swap (i.e. [Damerau-Levenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) distance)
2. for non-exact sequence match: this time probably only with Match and Swap operations. You can use free (zero-cost) Insert to get the words that should not be edited.

It should not be hard to implement. But the computational complexity will be quite high. I would use some heuristics to skip hopeless matches. Preprocessing words in the document and the edit list could be good: get a set of chars for each word to allow a quick comparison before calculating full edit distance), etc.

Comment: OK, I'll start Googling. Could you explain what you mean by "not be hard…but the complexity will be quite high"? Do you mean the complexity of my code will be high? That sounds hard to implement.

Comment: I meant computational complexity, i.e. it will be slow.